# Building list of items of different types in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, database-design

Suppose, that I have a database with the following tables:

- File
- Folder (relation File..Folder is *..1)
- Flower (which is neither a File, nor a Folder, it has completely different field set)

Now I want to create a data structure (may be single table, but if there is such need, there may be a few tables as well), which contains a list of items of different types: files, folders and flowers. I also would like this list to keep consistency of the data (foreign keys etc.).

Is it possible? If so, how can it be done?

The original tables may be modified, if needed. Let's say, that the database is a MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want a `View`, which is essentially a saved query. That way when the underlying tables change, you see the changes

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW MyStuff AS
SELECT 'Flower' AS [Type], [Name], NULL AS [Parent] 
--Flowers don't have a parent folder
FROM [Flower]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'File' AS [Type], [File].[Name], [Folder].[Name] AS [Parent]
FROM [File]
JOIN [Folder] ON [File].[FolderID] = [Folder].[ID] 
--Join on your foreign key
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Folder' AS [Type], [Folder].[Name], [ParentFolder].[Name] AS [Parent] 
--I am assuming folders have a parent (apart from the root)
FROM [Folder]
LEFT JOIN [Folder] AS ParentFolder ON [Folder].[ParentID] = [ParentFolder].[ID] 
--Left Join so that the root is also displayed
```

Comment: I guess, that this is the best solution I can get: I would have to standarize these data somewhere anyway and view is quite a good solution here. Thanks!

Comment: @Spook: I thought that was the essence of your question, i.e. *how* to standardise those data. Are you sure this answer is really what you were after?

Comment: I actually was seeking for a way of combining different data in a single query (or table) in such way, that application will be able later to distinguish them and get their specific data. Using view (along with types and IDs of objects) and standarizing the access to those different data is precisely what I was searching for.